# If I'm adding sounds on resource packs where should sound.json go?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

```
{
    "ak47_shot": {
        "sounds": [
            {
                "name": "custom/ak47_shot"
            } 
        ]
    },
    "ak47_reload": {
        "sounds": [
            {
                "name": "custom/ak47_reload"
            } 
        ]
    },
    "m79_shot": {
        "sounds": [
            {
                "name": "custom/m79_shot"
            } 
        ]
    },
    "m79_reload": {
        "sounds": [
            {
                "name": "custom/m79_reload"
            } 
        ]
    }
}
```

This is my `sound.json` file, and it doesn't work when I use `/playsound custom.ak47_shot master @a`
I'm not sure there is a problem with sound.json, but I think there is a problem.
Anyway, where should I put my `sound.json` file? I put it in `myresourcepack/assets/minecraft/sounds.json` right now.
There is a `myresourcepack/assets/minecraft/sounds` folder too, and I putted my custom sounds in there.
[image: h]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sounds.json` file is placed in `/assets/minecraft`, which means that your sound would be called upon by the ID of `minecraft:ak47_ahot`.

However, it is not recommended to use the `minecraft` namespace for custom sounds. You should rename your `minecraft` folder to something else, for example a suitable name would be `guns`.

Comment: If I put `sounds.json` and my sounds in `guns` folder, would my sound be called upon by the ID of `guns:ak47_shot`?

Comment: Also, is my `sounds.json` file written right? It is not working when I used `/playsound guns:ak47_shot master @a`

Comment: I put the picture of my resource pack