# Sound pack is not working even though sound.json's working fine

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

```
{
    "ak47_shot": {
        "sounds": [
            {
                "name": "custom/ak47_shot"
            } 
        ]
    },
    "ak47_reload": {
        "sounds": [
            {
                "name": "custom/ak47_reload"
            } 
        ]
    },
    "m79_shot": {
        "sounds": [
            {
                "name": "custom/m79_shot"
            } 
        ]
    },
    "m79_reload": {
        "sounds": [
            {
                "name": "custom/m79_reload"
            } 
        ]
    }
}
```

This is my `sound.json` file, and it doesn't play any sounds when I use `/playsound custom:ak47_shot master @a`.

I'm pretty sure there is no problem with `sounds.json` file because if I press `Tab` key, it shows the `custom:ak47_shot` `custom:ak47_reload` etc.

I putted my `sounds.json` file in in `/assets/custom/sounds.json`.

I putted my custom sounds in `/assets/custom/sounds/mysoundfiles.ogg`.

I guess my custom sounds' locations are wrong, but I'm not 100% sure. What might be a problem right now?
[image: Sound files]

Comment: This looks like pretty much the same question you posted before, you just changed a folder name.

Comment: If your question: [If I'm adding sounds on resource packs where should sound.json go?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/397103/if-im-adding-sounds-on-resource-packs-where-should-sound-json-go) didn't receive a satisfactory answer for the problem you described, you should edit it to include additional info so that we can provide an adequate answer. Please do not re-post your questions.